# Eclipse classic problems to update Java EE tools

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have Eclipse classic 4.2 installed in my PC and I wanted to work on the webservices project with eclipse. I have followed the following method to update the eclipse classic to support Java EE.

I have used the install new software section and added the following URL

[http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates/](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates)

Then i have selected Web tools platform and click next.

Then I'm getting the following error messages and i'm unable to install the web tools.

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: Eclipse Java EE Developer
>   Tools 3.2.0.v201005241530-7b7GHTYFSK2W9kPaFClvz0O_NQmN
>   (org.eclipse.jst.enterprise_ui.feature.feature.group
>   3.2.0.v201005241530-7b7GHTYFSK2W9kPaFClvz0O_NQmN)   Missing requirement: WTP EJB UI Plug-in 1.1.500.v201004280901
>   (org.eclipse.jst.ejb.ui 1.1.500.v201004280901) requires 'bundle
>   org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui [2.2.0,3.0.0)' but it could not be found
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools 3.2.0.v201005241530-7b7GHTYFSK2W9kPaFClvz0O_NQmN (org.eclipse.jst.enterprise_ui.feature.feature.group
>   3.2.0.v201005241530-7b7GHTYFSK2W9kPaFClvz0O_NQmN)
>       To: org.eclipse.jst.ejb.ui [1.1.500.v201004280901]

Can anyone guide me how to install and get started with the current version I have?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not install Eclipse 4.2 EE version? It will be quicker to do this than work out all the dependencies you need to install manually.

Comment: The reason is that with the current eclipse, i have configured the wowza, android and everything.. thats why want to work on the same :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use juno, http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno to install webtools on top of Eclipse 4.2.

The webtools repo you showed above doesn't have EMF in it, so you need to add an EMF repo as well *or* pull it from the juno update site.